# Running an apk as shell user via adb

Tags: android

I know it is possible to run a java main function with shell user UID via `adb shell app_process ....`, so similarly, is it possible to run an apk with shell user UID via adb shell? I tried `adb shell am start...`, but it doesn't seem to get the shell user permissions.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#am Take a look at the list of options for `start`

Comment: @Michael According to the documentation, if I don't pass "--user" it should work with the current user, but I've tested it and it doesn't work that way.  If I specify --user 2000, adb will report an error: "Activity class does not exist".